# ActionScript 3.0 Class

Tags: flash, class, actionscript, adobe

I got a question regarding actionscript classes. I want to know if there is anyway that i can have multiple classes in one fla? Or differenet classes on different frames or scenes? For example a tic-tac toe game on the second frame/scene and on third frame or scene a memory game (which need different external as. files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one document class per .fla - but you can have as many 'ordinary' classes as you like (which you can associate with movieclips but not scenes).

If you want to have multiple games within one 'package', the best way is to create separate flash movies (swf files) for each game, and then create a 'master' swf which loads each of the game swf files into itself.

Comment: Thnx for the tip. So i just export the swf then import the exported swf into my fla. on the stage? And that's it?

Comment: Usually, the swfs are loaded at runtime rather than imported into the fla - see http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html